# Achieving more than 5 domains on lightsail with route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

I have 5 domains that I would like to point to my lightsail instance.
example of my 5 domains:

```
www.domain1.com
www.domain2.com
www.domain3.com
www.domain4.com
www.domain5.com
```

Creating domain 1 to 3 is fairly easy by adding the nameserver to my DNS service provider which is Namecheap. everything worked perfectly. NGINX routed the different domain to the correct ports.

However, the max limit on lightsail is only 3 DNS zone. It states in the document that for my 4th and 5th domain I will need to use Route 53.

I registered domain 4 with route53 and added a hosted zone followed by creating a A record with the correct static IP address of my lightsail instance. However, my url is not showing that it is pointing to my lightsail instance. it is not even up when i check with [online dns checker](https://www.whatsmydns.net/)

I know it will work if I created a DNS zone in lightsail and link the nameserver to route53. however I have used up all my DNS zone for domain 1 to 3. So how can I create 500 domain like what Route 53 mention in their document??

So please show me some guidance in creating 5 domains that is able to point to a single instance in lightsail.

Comment: You don't need to modify any name servers. You would simply create an `A-Record` on NameCheap that points the domain name to the IP address of the Lightsail instance. Put all of these configurations in NameCheap, not AWS. Make sure you use a **Static IP address** on the Lightsail instance so that it does not change.

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, by doing that, I have issues with the client side rendering. I won't be able to go to www.domain1.com/subdomain

Comment: solved. for namecheap, just follow this guide: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/319/2237/how-can-i-set-up-an-a-address-record-for-my-domain/.